# eval() in Lightning Web Components

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, javascript-controller

This code works in JS

```
<script>
     let object_1 = "value";
     window.console.log(eval("object_" + 1));
</script>
```

But I try to do it in LWC and I get the error that the variable is "undefined":

```
   . . .
@api object_1;
   . . .
connectedCallback() {
    this.object_1 = "test";
    window.console.log(" 1: " + eval("this.object_" + 1) + " 2: " + eval("object_" + 1));
}
```

And the error that gives me:

```
"afterRender threw an error in 'c:my_component' [object_1 is not defined]"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax for the second eval() misses  `this` keyword while referring object_1

```
connectedCallback() {
        this.object_1 = "test";
        console.log(" 1: " + eval("this.object_" + 1) + " 2: " + eval("this.object_" + 1));
    }
```

Playground Link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/MIpc94lRV/1/edit

Comment: It still does not work in chrome & mozilla, but in IE 11 the function interprets the string with a warning of: SEC7131: Security of a sandboxed iframe is potentially compromised by allowing script and same origin access. Can it be that security issues do not work in other browsers?

Comment: Wiered. Works in playground though. Might worth raising case with SF to get clarification. I tried same in locker console and seems eval is fine. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console

Comment: Any idea why the "eval" parameter interprets it as "undefined"? Because in the same Sandbox I have another problem with the "loadstyle" function that in IE 11 works but in the rest of the browsers it does not.

Comment: @AlexM. Try in some developer org... If you can replicate it

Comment: I read that it can be by the Lightning Locker. @PranayJaiswal